# Right clicking an app icon on the taskbar does not work

Tags: windows-10

Right clicking an app icon on the taskbar does not open menu to pin to taskbar, open recent files etc.
Left clicking notification (down in the right corner) does not open notification menu (+ settings).

Comment: Run [sfc /scannow](https://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/2895-run-sfc-command-windows-10-a.html).

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but I did not work.
I ran "sfc /scannow", it found corrupt files but could not fix them.
I then ran "Dism /Online /Cleanup-Image /RestoreHealth", but it could not fix them either.